# What happens when Memstore crashes in Hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

How Region server will respond when MEMSTORE have failed in a HBASE cluster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I explain this a lot to companies we support at Splice Machine (Open Source).

The records that are in the memstore (memory) also have corresponding Write Ahead Log Records.  When a record is inserted into the memstore, it is also appended to the write ahead log.  If a memstore crashes (i.e. regionserver crashes), zookeeper will identify the node failure and the HBase Master node will re-assign the region to another node.  The other node before bringing up the region, will read the write ahead logs from HDFS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!